# Load more tag related entries using Ajax

Tags: solspace, tags, solspace-tag

I am using Tag module (v 4.2.3) with EE (v 2.5.2),and I have requirement wherein on a products details page I have to show its 6 related products based on tags which I am achieving using the following expression

{exp:tag:related_entries channel="product" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" orderby="relevance" limit="6"}
{title}
{/exp:tag:related_entries}

Now we have a button below the 6 related products,and on click of it we have to load 6 more related products.I am not able to exclude the existing 6 products on the page,I have the already loaded products entry_ids but I am not able to write a expression of tag related entries with which I can exclude the already loaded products and load the next batch of 6 products.
  Please help me out in achieving that,I would be really thankful

Cheers
Nisar

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `offset=""` parameter? For example, to get the next 6 related entries:

```
{exp:tag:related_entries 
   channel="product"
   entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" 
   orderby="relevance" 
   limit="6" 
   offset="6"}
```